# Obfuscate grails application

Tags: java, web-applications, grails, obfuscation

Has anyone had any success with obfuscating a Grails application with a tool such as ProGuard (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)?

I suspect that it's actually not possible to do this, since much for Grails relies on Groovy's dynamic language features, 
for example:

- Matching missing methods to field names to configure domain classes;
- Mapping URLs to controller classes and fields/methods;
- Matching tags to tag library classes and methods.

That's most of a grails app that would have to be excluded. Has anyone tried and succeeded / failed?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried and decided that there is no need in obfuscation grails application. Grails uses Groovy which compiles code in obfuscated like way.

Comment: thanks @Mr. Cat for your replay. Using which tool you have tried for obfuscate?

Comment: is it your opinion, after your fully affort?

Comment: Proguard. Actually not fully. I wanted to obfuscate classes from src/java then, but give up cos very few classes usually in this folder.

Comment: Did you try to obfuscate .war file?

Comment: Is there a way to obfuscate the war file produced by STS\Grails Tools\Grails 
Command Wizard\(war command)\... ?

Comment: what type of difficulty you have faced?

Comment: can I have those links you referred in past?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30273/discussion-between-mr-cat-and-an5607ky)

Comment: @Mr.Cat I know this post is from very long time ago. is it possible that you can explain your reasoning that you gave in above answer? it's not clear and i see you had some offline chat...and the summary was never added into stackoverflow. thanks in advance!